# What happen when delete shared memory files in dev/shm by using 'rm' command

Tags: linux, posix, shared-memory

I used Posix shared memory to communicate between 2 process. Then during 2 process were sharing data, I used 'rm' command to remove all shared file which mounted in dev/shm. I expected some errors will happen, but everything still work normal.

So I have a question as below:
What happen when I using rm command line to delete all shared memory files in dev/shm directory.
I have googled but cannot find anywhere discuss about this situation.

Can anyone please explain to me about it?

Thanks so much

Comment: In unix/linux, files are deleted from disk only when all the references to them are closed. A file name in a directory is simply a reference to a file, and so is a (open) file handle in a running program. Even if you delete the file name, the running program still has a handle, so the file is not really deleted - but you can not see it because the file name in the directory is gone.

Comment: Thanks @linuxfan so much for your answer. I'm just a Linux newbie, I will continue google for this.